# Electrical Current Series Circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Why is the current within a series circuit the same through all components?

If we had two resistors one with 6 Ohms of resistance and the other with 2 Ohms, shouldn't the current be greater at the resistor with less resistance? The way I understand it, is that resistors slow down the movement of electrons, and if there is two resistors with different resistance they should slow down the movement of electrons differently, so the current should be different by Ohms law.

What is the flaw in my intuition?

Comment: A 6 ohm resistor and a 2 ohm resistor have different currents through them if there is the same voltage applied. If you connect them in series, then you don't apply the same voltage to each one.

Comment: Do you drive a car?

Answer (score 0):

Think of electrons as people in a mall. To exit, they must pass through two doors - a larger one and a narrower one.

Now the fire alarm rings and they all rush to exit.

- **If the narrow door is first**, so that, say, 10 people can pass through it per second, then these same 10 people will also pass through the larger door each second. Even though the larger door *would allow* for more people per second, there aren't that many people available for it. So the flow of people per second through both will be equal.
- **If the larger door is first**, then, say, 100 people can pass through it per second. But they are then slowed down at the next door since only 10 people can pass through this one. So they must queue up. And this queue will extend through the first, larger door so that they all move slower. Even though the larger *would have* allowed for 100 people passing though per second, only 10 actually will pass through since the queue reaches a steady state so that every one in the queue moves at equal speed.

Now, replace door width with resistance and people-per-second with current (charge-per-second).*

The current through both resistors will very quickly reach steady state which means that it is the same through them both when in series. Ohm's law still holds true, though, since the voltages will change. Basically, the people "pressure" will be larger through the narrower door than through the larger door, corresponding to a larger electronic "pressure", meaning voltage, across a more resistive resistor.

---

<sup>* *This analogy is not perfect, since, for instance, we for circuits have to add together the resistances to find the total resistance effect which might not make intuitive sense for the door example. But for initial intuitive idea, it can be usual for visualizing the point. Another often-used analogy is water pressure in a pipe which filters or narrow sections representing resistors, the water pressure representing voltage and the water flow rate representing current.*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another argument from a different angle:

Intensity of the electric current is defined as $i=\frac{dq}{dt}$.

If intensity had different values at two different points along the same wire (or near two resistances in series), charges would deplete or accumulate at some points.

In fact this can happen at extremely high frequencies, but that's well outside the field of electricity, which is defined as a low frequency approximation where Kirchhoff's circuit laws are valid. In fact, Kirchhoff's current law is precisely the one that prevents the scenario you're suggesting.

Historically, electricy was devised with a formalism inspired by fluid mechanics, so until the electron was discovered some scientists thought of electricity as a pair of "fluids" (one positive, one negative) that flowed inside conductors. Both theories have a "current vector" which flux is an important value (respectively, flow rate and intensity), a conservation law (mass or charge)...

This analogy works quite, if you see voltage as a difference in altitude and current as the flow of a river: in normal circumstances, the flow of the river is mostly constant in spite of altitude variations, just like current is constant along a branch in spite of voltage variations.